# Virtual pageview in place of real pageview in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, pageviews

I'd like to have better error page reporting in Google Analytics.  Currently, if someone does something on my site which causes a problem, they see an error page instead of the content they expected.  The URL remains the same.  So if they went to www.example.com/view_my_profile and there was a problem with their profile, they would see an error page at that URL.

What I'd like to do is send Google Analytics a virtual pageview of something like www.example.com/error/view_my_profile/ (maybe an event captures the extra parameters better?).  That's easy enough.  But I want this virtal pageview to happen instead of the /view_my_profile real pageview.  Because that real page wasn't actually viewed and it would be registering an extra pageview on my site.

Is this as simple as leaving out the _trackPageView call in the google analytics snippet below or am I asking for trouble?

```
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-${gaAccount}-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way over-complicating things..just use _trackPageView like normal but pass a value (virtual URL) to it for the URL you want it to be.  It will count as a page view for the URL you pass it instead of the current URL.

Comment: IOW when you pass a value to _trackPageView, it counts as a page view for that value, not the current URL.  So you can pass "www.example.com/error/view_my_profile/" or whatever other custom URL for your 404 page and it will count for that, not the "real" page

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without complication. As long as you load ga.js, instantiate `var gaq`, and set the account, you can make any calls you want, including `_trackPageview` with only a virtual pageview value.

You don't even need to call the organic `_trackPageview` -- you could just do event tracking. In fact, you might want to consider doing an organic pageview, coupled with an Event Tracking that passes some detailed error tracking info to you. Because there can be up to 4 parameters, you can log more and better structured data.

So, on your 404 page, you could call something like:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', '404 Error', location.pathname, document.referrer, time_stamp_value]);
```

(where you've previously defined time_stamp_value as a non-float Number.)

Something that simple will allow you to create hierarchies for your errors, count them more easily, and even do things like the referring page and a timestamp value, without cluttering your pageview information.

Comment: I don't want to count the pageview as they're not really viewing that page..  tracking an event makes sense I guess, but they are viewing the error page so virtual pageview seems to make more sense.  GA will have the referrer and the timestamp (has the timestamp for events too, curious why you felt that was necessary?).

Comment: @at it does have referrer, but it can be a bit of a pain to peter out. This is just an example of what you could do; my point is that it's a more flexible way to transmit data. It doesn't really have the time-stamp; it has the date, and in some views, the hour during which it took place, but rarely much more.

Comment: @at There's also no harm in doing both. What I would do is capture a pageview that simply signifies that they viewed an error page, and track an Event with detailed information about the type of error. That way, it doesn't break navigation path summaries, and you'll be able to get better logged error data.